# How to concatenate Int variable in the SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to write a select query with concatenating the stored procedure Exec in the select results.

This is the actual stored procedure execution result

```
exec wf_Move_bills ''' + billid+ ''',361,14098,14100, ''+ binid +'' ,''' + @comment + '''
```

`BinId` is an Integer. I am having trouble on concatenating with my query.

Result is returned as:

```
exec wf_Move_bills 'XZ242344',361,14098,14100, '+ binid +' ,'Moved by Dev :'
```

Expected result is:

```
exec wf_Move_bills 'XZ242344',361,14098,14100, 300 ,'Moved by Dev :'
```

Because in the stored procedure, parameter for `binid` is `int` with length = 4

```
declare @comment nvarchar(4000) 
set @comment= 'Moved by Dev:'

select 
    *,
    'exec wf_Move_bills ''' + billid+ ''',361,14098,14144, ''+ binid +'' ,''' + @comment + ''' '
from 
    billingtable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is overloaded.  That is, it means both string concatenation and addition.  If any value is numeric, then it is addition, and you get an error.

So, do an explicit `cast`:

```
select *, 
       'exec wf_Move_bills ''' + billid+ ''',361,14098,14100, ''' + cast(binid as varchar(255)) +''' ,''' + @comment + '''
```

Alternatively, I often use replace for this type of logic:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max);
set @str = 'exec wf_Move_bills @billid, 361, 14098, 14100, @binid, ''@comment''';

set @str = replace(@str, '@billid', @billid);
set @str = replace(@str, '@binid', @binid);
set @str = replace(@str, '@comment', replace(@comment, '''', '''''');
```

Note:  this also gives an opportunity to handle any single quotes in the comment.

You may also be able to do variable substitution using `sp_executedql`.

Comment: still i am getting the result as exec wf_Move_bills 'XZ100000',361,14098,14144, '+ cast(binid as varchar(255)) +' ,'Testing'

Answer (score 0):

change `''+ binid +''` to `''+ convert(varchar(10), binid) +''`